# What is the algebra behind the manipulation of exponents shown here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$8(8^k) - 3(3^k)$ is the first step, and then it gets manipulated into.

$(8^k - 3^k)8 + 5(3^k)$ this manipulation is correct as they do hold the same values when inputting a value for $k$ but I do not understand how the manipulation occurred?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you didn't put much effort into solving this yourself. You could just have multiplied $(8^k-3^k)8$ to $8(8^k)-8(3^k)$ and then see $-3(8^k)+5(3^k)=(-3+5)(3^k)$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
8(8^k)-3(3^k)&= 8(8^k)-(8-5)(3^k)\\
&= 8 (8^k)-8(3^k)+5(3^k)\\
&=8(8^k-3^k)+5(3^k)
\end{align}

Comment: where did the (8-5) comes from in the first step??

Comment: We have $8-5=3$

Comment: @eewfewfwf $3=8-5$

Answer (score 0):

We have $8(8^k)-3(3^k)$, subtracting and adding $5(3^k)$ gives $8(8^k)-8(3^k)+5(3^k) = 8(8^k-3^k)+5(3^k)$.

Q.E.D

Comment: wait why are we adding $5(3^k)$

Comment: We subtracted and then added $5(3^k)$, so the net result is zero so we're allowed to and so we could factor out the 8

Answer (score 0):

$$8(8^k) - 3(3^k)=8(8^k) -(8-5)(3^k)   $$

$$8(8^k) - 8(3^k) +5(3^k)=$$

$$8(8^k-3^k) +5(3^k)$$